# Google Looker 'Can't Embed due to provider site restrictions'

Tags: embed, looker

I am trying to embed Quicksights visuals into Google Looker Studio.

Using Quicksights GenerateEmbedUrlForRegisteredUserCommand. The link works in a regular browser window and when adding and iframe INTO Google Looker Studio via "Edit as HTML" in google Chrome developer tools Elements.

I've setup domain permissions for everything *.google.com, I've setup frame-ancestors and x-frame-options to allow embedding via Iframe (green arrows show me updating google lookers html to make sure Iframe content was loaded and x-frame-options or frame-ancestors headers are working).

BUT once I input the URL into the "URL Embed Properties" I am not able to see the visual and get the error "Can't embed due to provider site restrictions"

**HELP PLEASE, as I am out of ideas.**

**!IMPORTANT! StackOverflow marked me as spam so `http` stands for `https://` below, sry for the confusion**

Tried 2 implementations, both of which **rendered** in the **HTML(using google chromes developers tools and manually editing HTML by adding an iframe, showing that all permissions are good and that there should be no restrictions)** but **NOT via the "URL Embed Properties"**:

1. Lambda returns a 301 redirect with the location to the Quicksights Visual - HTML iframe inserting via developer tools elements tab loads the data into the report, using the "URL Embed" does not.
   Lambda response:

```
    const response = {
        statusCode: 301,
        headers: {
            Location: commandResponse.EmbedUrl,
            'X-Frame-Options': 'allow-from httplookerstudio.google.com;',
            'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors 'self' http*.google.com http*.amazon.com http*.us-east-1.on.aws;"
        },
    };
```

2. Lambda returns an HTML page, with embedded content in the page - HTML iframe inserting via developer tools elements tab loads the data into the report, using the "URL Embed" does not.

```
    const html = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="${commandResponse.EmbedUrl} width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
    </body>
    </html>`
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            Location: commandResponse.EmbedUrl,
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
            'X-Frame-Options': 'allow-from httplookerstudio.google.com;',
            'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors 'self' http*.google.com <hp>*.amazon.com http*.us-east-1.on.aws;"
        },
        body: html
    };
```

Screenshot Below of what I am talking about:
[cantEmbedIntoLooker_ChromeDeveloperToolsHTMLIframe_VS_LookerUrlEmbed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7HWm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The `ALLOW-FROM` [directive is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) and can't be used reliably

You're already using the Content Security Policy frame-ancestors directive so I don't think you need the `ALLOW-FROM` directive anyway

Try temporarily removing the `X-Frame-Options` from the header completely and see if that helps

---

I haven't used Quicksights before but it might be related to permissions or maybe a missing step
Could you verify [this AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/embed-interactive-dashboards-in-your-application-with-amazon-quicksight/) and make sure you're not missing anything? Step 3 (getting the embedded URL) might be related

Also make sure your [IAM permissions are correct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/embed-an-amazon-quicksight-dashboard-in-a-local-angular-application.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Unfortunately that did not work.

Here is the lambda responses I've Tried:
```
const response = {
        statusCode: 301,
        headers: {
            Location: commandResponse.EmbedUrl,
            'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.google.com https://*.amazon.com https://*.us-east-1.on.aws;"
        },
    };
```

Also tried a more simple approach:

```
        headers: {
            Location: commandResponse.EmbedUrl,
            'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors https://*.google.com"
        },
```

Comment: My goodness, sorry that looks so horrible, looks like there is mini markdown in comments.

I've also tried the simplest since I know the exact domain of the test Report I have.

I took out the X-Frame-Options and left only 'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors [https://lookerstudio.google.com](https://lookerstudio.google.com)"

Still getting "Can't embed due to provider site restrictions."

Comment: Hmm can you temporarily try removing `Content-Security-Policy` from the header as well just to see if it's related to the error?

Comment: Removed the `CSP` header as well. Was able to load it in the Iframe using the Developer Tools in Chrome via HTML inserting in elements tab but the "URL Embed" component in Google Looker is still saying "Can't embed due to provider site restrictions"

Comment: It might be related to IAM permissions. Can you check the edits I made to my answer?

Comment: Hey Fearless, thanks so much for all your help and time! Currently swamped with other things but will come back to this in a week.
I got the implementation from these docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/embedding-visuals.html, but had to do more IAM work. Had to add the quicksights user to the IAM role as well as one other thing. Have quickly skimmed the docs you've sent and they look very informative thanks!

Comment: @SergeySarkisyan no problem. Hope the docs can help pinpoint the issue